# Simplify $a^2\dfrac{(a+b)(a+c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+b^2\dfrac{(b+c)(b+a)}{(b-c)(b-a)}+c^2\dfrac{(c+a)(c+b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $a^2\dfrac{(a+b)(a+c)}{(a-b)(a-c)}+b^2\dfrac{(b+c)(b+a)}{(b-c)(b-a)}+c^2\dfrac{(c+a)(c+b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}$

$\Rightarrow -a^2\dfrac{(a+b)(a+c)}{(a-b)(c-a)}-b^2\dfrac{(b+c)(b+a)}{(b-c)(a-b)}-c^2\dfrac{(c+a)(c+b)}{(c-a)(b-c)}$

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{-a^2(a+b)(a+c)(b-c)-b^2(b+c)(b+a)(c-a)-c^2(c+a)(c+b)(a-b)}{(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)}$

So I suppose at this juncture I could just do the multiplication of the brackets in the numerator. But as you can see it will be very tedious and time-consuming, resulting in fifth-order variables and a total tally of 24 terms. My question is for the numerator, is there a way to simplify so I don't have to carry out multiplying the brackets? Because currently I don't see any way (for example taking out a common factor). Thank you.

Comment: Summing up yields
$$
a^2 + 2ab + 2ac + b^2 + 2bc + c^2=(a+b+c)^2.
$$

Comment: You can use symmetry and only expand one of the numerators, the just rename symbols to get what the others will be. That seems like a significant time-saver to me.

Comment: So the numerator is equal to $a^2+2ab+2ac+b^2+2bc+c^2$. Is there a way to get this without actually multiplying out everything? Thanks.

Comment: I see that each term has a common factor of $(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$, so we can factor it out:

$= -(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)\left[ a(a+b)(a+c) + b(b+c)(b+a) + c(c+a)(c+b) \right]$
But I am not sure this hints is helpful.

Comment: @YaoshengDeng : Your expression is of degree six and includes terms like $a^5c$ which won't cancel. So it can't equal the given fifth-degree numerator.

Comment: You are correct that the expression I provided is of degree six and cannot be equal to the given fifth-degree numerator. Thanks for pointing this mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing the numerator with $b=c$ is easily seen to nullify it. Hence, by symmetry, $(b-c)(c-a)(a-b)$ is a factor. The next-simplest factor to test for is $a+b+c$. Indeed, we strike lucky: substituting $-a$ for $b+c$ nullifies the numerator too. All that's left for the remaining, linear, factor is $a+b+c$ again. To check the numerical factor, test with some simple numbers—say $a=0$, $b=1$, and $c=2$, which gives it as $1$. After cancelling with the denominator, the result is
$$(a+b+c)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite follow why you can set $b=c$, because doesn't that make the entire equation equal to 0? Second, what do you mean by symmetry? I don't understand this term or concept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

The [Lagrange interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) at nodes $a$, $b$, $c$ for the function $f$ is

$$L_{f,(a,b,c)}(x) \colon =f(a) \frac{(x-b)(x-c)}{(a-b)(a-c)} + f(b) \frac{(x-a)(x-c)}{(b-a)(b-c)} + f(c)\frac{(x-a)(x-b)}{(c-a)(c-b)}$$

Now if $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$ then $L_{f,(a,b,c)}(x) \equiv f(x)$.

Now, can you guess what is $f$, and what is the particular value of $x$ we should consider?

> The function is $f(x)=x^2$, to be evaluated at $x=a+b+c$